# Nested Layouts ScrollView

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I've been struggling with this for a while and been unable to find an answer so far.
I have a TableLayout inside a RelativeLayout. I need the TableLayout to be scrollable, not the relative layout as it has static buttons I don't plan on them moving.

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:layout_weight="1">
     <RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Encuestas" >
     <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:onClick="SyncServer"
    android:text="Sync" />

         <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1" >

        </TableLayout>


 </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

With this code I can scroll the entire screen, but if I try to put the ScrollView on the TableLayout, I'm unable to click on the button I created.

```
 <RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".Encuestas" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:onClick="SyncServer"
    android:text="Sync" />
   <ScrollView

  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
  android:layout_weight="1">
  <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1" >


 </TableLayout>

  </ScrollView>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

This one doesn't allow me to click on the button. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it is probably due to the fact that `ScrollView` is being added to the layout after the `Button`, and is configured to match the height and width of the parent so it is above the `Button` in the z-index. Try adding the `Button` after the `ScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks Manveer Chawla. I forgot thes ScrollView was in front of the button.

Comment: If this works for you, should I post this as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never put a scrollable view inside another scrollable view (that scrolls the same direction). The only exception to this rule is when the Lord appears before you in all his glory and hands you stone tablets engraved with something that says otherwise.

Anyway, the second layout will work with one small modification, you must tell the layout to put the scrollview beneath the button like so:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/button1"
    android:layout_weight="1">
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Worked like a charm. Also Manveer Chawla comments works